# xpath php sort attribute based on greater than date

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Need to xpath xml data based on greater than date attribute. The dashes in the date below prevent the greater than symbol from working. Is there a way to remove the dashes in the xml on the fly?

XML

```
<revisions>
  <revision date="2010-07-12">blah</revision>
  <revision date="2010-06-12">blah</revision>
</revisions>
```

PHP

```
$rdate = 2010-07-01;
$programs = $item->xpath("/programs/program[revisions/revision[@date>'".$rdate."']]");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try:

```
$rdate = 20100701;

/programs/program[revisions/revision[translate(@date,'-','') > '20100701']
```

Edit: one should note that in XPath 2.0 the `compare()` function is available (-1 smaller, 0 equal, 1 higher), so you can just compare strings. As far is I know most PHP implementations are still using XPath 1.0 though.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
str_replace($date, '-', '')
```